# Check if character is upper case in older c-style

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

I'm working on a lab that requires password authentication as both an older c-string and a string class. I have the string class version working. I've gotten the password entered as an array using `cin.getline(password, 20)`

`strlen(password)` also works correctly.

I've been searching for how to determing is the older c-string version contains an uppercase letter in any of it's values. Everything is saying to use `isupper`, which is from the newer string class(as far as I can tell).

Is there a way to do this? I'm considering just verifying using the string class version then inputting it into the char array.

Comment: Note the fastest way to do this in plain c, if you are able to assume an English ascii based system is to use (foo>='A' && foo<='Z'). That will tell you if a char is upper case.

Comment: `isupper` _is only_ in the old C library, it's not in the newer string class at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that `C` uses ASCII, you could create your own function:

```
bool upper(char chr)
{
    return chr >= 'A' && chr <= 'Z'; // same as return chr >= 65 && chr <= 90
}
```

Comment: I suggest using symbolic 'A' and 'Z' to avoid encoding differences on some systems and make the code clearer

Comment: Although assuming ASCII or an ASCII compatible encoding is not exactly a risky assumption, pedantically speaking, it is not correct to say "C uses ASCII".

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You can edit the answer, if you think it would be better ;)

Comment: This is somewhat of a trivial function, but in general it's probably a bad idea to re-create functions that already exist in the standard libraries. 1. The Standard Library implementations are likely to be fast, correct, and heavily tested. 2. You don't need additional lines of code in your project to maintain, update, debug.

Comment: @jwismar For people who are learning how to program, writing a function is a daily routine function.

Comment: @jwismar Just because the OP did not vote your beautiful copied answer, does not mean you have to get angry with me.

Comment: @jwismar And probably the OP wanted something like my answer, and not like yours, do you agree?

Answer (score 4):

There is a function called [`isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) in the C standard library, which takes a single character as an argument. (It doesn't matter where the character comes from, a C string or somewhere else.) This is probably what you are meant to use.

Answer (score 3):

There is an `isupper()` function in the C standard library, as well - in `<ctype>`

It takes a char parameter, so you would need to iterate over the character array and call it for each character.

There's some good information about it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isupper.htm).